# Perl search and replace multiple strings in one pass

Tags: perl

I have the following Perl code, which works without any error. I am wondering if it is possible to make the four replacements in the foreach loop in one pass and delete the whole line matching the fifth replacement.
I do not understand the suggested solutions I have gone through so far, I am trying to avoid using hashes.
I will be most appreciative.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
                                                                            
my @data=<DATA>;
foreach $lines (@data){
$lines =~ s/\//9/g;
$lines =~ s/333/33300/g;
$lines =~ s/555/55500/g;
$lines =~ s/=|==//g;
$lines =~ s/NIL|N I L//g;       # preferably delete this whole line
}

print "@lines\n";
exit 0;


__DATA__
63740 32575 40606 10217 20159 48528 83230 333 20/// 59008 83820=
63820 32580 20803 10305 20225 40130 82200 333 20262 59009 82823==
63135 NIL=
63742 12570 10507 10208 20148 48509 60014 81100 333 20155 59012 81820=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
my %map = (
   '/'   => '9',
   '333' => '33300',
   '555' => '55500',
   '='   => '',
);

my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys(%map);
my $re = qr/($pat)/;

while (<>) {
   next if /NIL/;
   s/$re/$map{$1}/g;
   print;
}
```

---

The above works because the string matched is the key of the translation map. But you want to add the following:

```perl
s/^.*NIL.*\z//
```

There's no simple way to handle that generically. But we could handle that case specially.

```perl
my %map = (
   '/'   => '9',
   '333' => '33300',
   '555' => '55500',
   '='   => '',
);

my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys(%map);
my $re = qr/^.*NIL.*\z|($pat)/;

while (<>) {
   s/$re/ defined($1) ? $map{$1} : "" /eg;
   print;
}
```

This is uglier, though possibly faster. Faster yet would be loading the entire file into memory.

```perl
my %map = (
   '/'   => '9',
   '333' => '33300',
   '555' => '55500',
   '='   => '',
   '=='  => '',
);

my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys(%map);
my $re = qr/^.*NIL.*\n?|($pat)/m;

local $/;
while (<>) {
   s/$re/ defined($1) ? $map{$1} : "" /eg;
   print;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @ikegami, this does exactly what I want. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Sorry to come back to you @ikegami. The answer is excellent, but when I read data from a file and write the modified data to another file I have a small problem. The print statement prints the modified data ok but starts each line with GLOB(0x56544d5f41e0). When I add "print $OUT_F". OUT_F being the file name the file is empty. The only changes I made are "while (<$IN_F>) {" and "print $OUT_F" inside the while loop.

Comment: @Zilore Mumba I think the print statement should be `print $OUT_F $_;` or `print $OUT_F $_, "\n";`

Comment: `print` is short for `print $_` but `print $var` is not short for `print $var $_`. If you want to print `$_` to a handle, you'll need to specify it explicitly

Comment: @ikegami, sorry to take your time, but for my learning, what are we doing in my $spat = ; and what does $re do? what does s/^.*NIL.*\z// replace?

Comment: Re "*what are we doing in my $spat = ;*", Getting the keys, replacing them with a regex pattern that matches those keys, then combining those patterns into a pattern that matches any of them.

Comment: Re "*and what does $re do?*", It's a variable whose value is the compiled regex pattern we need.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami, the explanations are clear. In the last one I guessed we were replacing NIL with nothing but I was wondering about z. I did not try it. Thanks once more.